# JavaFX: Strange case with DataView fill operation

Tags: javafx

I have a very strange problem with my test application. I need to fill the JavaFX TableView element with some data. Here is the code:

**fxmldocumentController.java**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import javafx.scene.control.TableView; //A
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn; //B
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory; //C
public class fxmldocumentController implements Initializable 
{

@FXML
private TableView<employees> mainTableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<employees, Integer> age;

@FXML
private TableColumn<employees, String> userName, companyName;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
{
  // TODO:
  mainTableView.getItems().
add(new employees("Yuri P. Bodrov", "VMware", 35));
  mainTableView.getItems().
add(new employees("Ivan Y. Bodrov", "VMware", 5));
  mainTableView.getItems().
add(new employees("Peter Y. Bodrov", "VMware", 2));

  // A problem starts here:
  age.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("age"));
  userName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("userName"));
  companyName.
setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("companyName"));


}   

}
```

**fxmldocument.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="400.0" style="-fx-
background-color: white;" 
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="sampletableviewapp00.fxmldocumentController">
<children>
  <Label fx:id="testLabel" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" style="-fx-
background-color: white;" text="Employees. TableView." textFill="#505050">
     <font>
        <Font size="14.0" />
     </font>
  </Label>
  <TableView fx:id="mainTableView" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="50.0" 
prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="377.0">
    <columns>
      <TableColumn prefWidth="90.0" text="UserName" />
      <TableColumn prefWidth="119.0" text="CompanyName" />
      <TableColumn prefWidth="84.0" text="Age" />
    </columns>

  </TableView>
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Sampletableviewapp00.java**

```
package sampletableviewapp00;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Sampletableviewapp00 extends Application 
{

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception 
{
  Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().
getClassLoader().getResource("fxmldocument.fxml"));

Scene scene = new Scene(root);

stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  launch(args);
}

}
```

**employees.java**

```
package sampletableviewapp00;

public class employees 
{
String userName, companyName;
int age;

// Generate Properties. Getters:
public int GetAge()
{
  return age;
}

public String GetUserName()
{
  return userName;
}

public String GetCompanyName()
{
  return companyName;
}

// Generate Properties. Setters:
public void SetAge(int age)
{
  this.age = age;
}

public void SetUserName(String userName)
{
  this.userName = userName;
}

public void SetCompanyName(String companyName)
{
  this.companyName = companyName;
}

// Generate Constructor of Employees class:
public employees(String userName, String companyName, int age)
{
  this.userName = userName;
  this.companyName = companyName;
  this.age = age;
}

}
```

When I run this application the NetBeans IDE 8.2 returns this stack of exceptions/errors: see outputError.png as attachment

[outputError.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILOij.png)

[outputError02.PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGC7D.png)

Dear colleagues! Do you have any ideas to resolve this problem? Could you try to write this code by yourself and run? Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Post exception.

Comment: Here we go! As picture...

Comment: Load your FXML without `ClassLoader`. `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxmldocument.fxml"));`

Comment: The same thing...`code`Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxmldocument.fxml")); :-(

Answer (score 1):

You have **fxmldocument.xml** but tried to load "**fxmldocument.fxml**".
Rename the file to have fxml extension.

Also make sure you put the fxml file under /resources/yourpackagepath/ folder and load as:

```
Sampletableviewapp00.class.getResource("fxmldocument.fxml")
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is triggering the exception:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().
getClassLoader().getResource("fxmldocument.fxml"));
```

Your fxml document's extension is xml in your project and you are trying to load it as .fxml in the above line.

Rename **fxmldocument.xml** to **fxmldocument.fxml**.

Comment: Thank you for your answers respected colleagues, but I made a mistake: actually, since the beginning, the filename fxmldocument.fxml has a FXML extension. Look at the picture in attachment: outputError02.PNG

Comment: Dear colleagues! Do you have any ideas to resolve this problem? Could you try to write this code by yourself and run? Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Everything there is fine, take a deep look at the files' names maybe you messed out on small detail. I already upvoted your question so it gets more attention.

Comment: It worked? If still you can come on chat we troubleshoot it together

Comment: No. Thanks for your update! :-) What about tomorrow? Where are you from Oussama?
Actually this problem is a reeeal stuck! :-(

Comment: I'm from Tunisia, if you need to contact me here is my website http://dainer.me/, there you can find all my social network accounts.

Comment: I just sent to you a LinkedIn Invitation.